# PHP Functions Classes Methods Confusion

Tags: php, class, function

I am working on some legacy code at the moment and stumbled across a weird class/function call that php.net doesn't seem to explain and I've never seen before:

```
if(security::instance()->check_client()) {
```

There is a class security, and there are functions named instance and check_client inside that class. But this seems to call two functions in one statement and pass the one to the other, or at least thats what the outcome suggests.
Can someone clarify this one for me?

Comment: The [static keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) (used for static functions) is explained in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classical implementation of the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

I suppose your class `security` looks like this :

```
class security {
    private static $instance = null;

    private function __construct() {}        

    public static function instance() {
        if (null === self::$instance)
            self::$instance = new security();

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function check_client() { /* do something */ }
}
```

What it does is that the static method instance returns an instance of the class security; Which mean that `security::instance() instanceof security === true`

That's why you can chain the call to the check_client() method as in your exemple

```
security::instance()->check_client()
```

This is similar to

```
$secu = security::instance();
$secu->check_client();
```

Comment: Hi Alfwed, thank you very much for this thorough explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The execution goes like this:

- first, the [static method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29#Static_methods) `instance()` of the `security` class is executed
- it returns an instance of the `security` class  (most likely)
- then, the `check_client` method is executed on the returned object

So, since `security::instance()` is an object, you can call a method on it.

Comment: How do you know it returns an instance of the security class? :)

Comment: That was just a guess, based on OPs statement that a method `check_client` exists in the code

Answer (score 1):

**security:instance()**

is a static call (so probably a static method)

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

which returns an instance of some class, which has a **member method check_client()**

so it returns an object, then you can call any public method on that object.

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume (as I don't know the underlying code), but it might explain it to you.

First of all functions can return objects. You then call an objects function on the returned object:

```
security::instance()->check_client()
```

Is the same like:

```
$securityInstance = security::instance();
$securityInstance->check_client();
```

Next to that, by the naming of `instance` I would assume that `security::instance()` returns the instance of the a security class, probably a singleton implementation or a factory based on the applications configuration.